# KendoUI or DevExpress for inexpirienced with Javascript?

Tags: telerik, devexpress, kendo-ui

I come from a Powerbuilder background and our company made a shift to .NET.

We discuss about what platform to use. .NET, Web, C#, Entity Framework for the moment but we need a "client" component solution...something a bit RAD (if there is such in web development)

We know very little apbout javascript, json etc

Having that in mind, which platform do you think is easier to develop with, KendoUI or DevExpress?

I have only seen Kendo

(we want the client thing...the whole server components matter made us stay in PB for so long)

Waiting your advices! Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience, the DevExpress DXTREME offers the framework and corresponding wizards that allow you to create prototypes of the [multi-channel applications](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/mobile.xml) (for iOS and Android) quickly.

At the same time, the Kendo UI provides [more "clear" access](http://www.kendoui.com/mobile.aspx) to the used widgets' JavaScript code. But it may require additional effort with the JavaScript.

In any case, I belive you can decide only once you try to build something using both of them. It is still up to you. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I may be biased here as i work for Telerik as an evangelist. Having said that i am a hard core programmer myself so this is based on my experience.

I was more of a windows platform guy for more than 5 years now and my work made me shift to this. But i had started out as a web guy almost 10 years ago. When I started to look at web as building myself back on the web around couple of years ago, I had to start understanding JQuery as that has become the default JS in my opinion. So when kendo came out - it was as if Kendo was complimenting JQuery. No new syntax or no new learning curve for me. Of course being a framework it has its own methods, properties and events that's it but no new language.

Another biggest factor with kendo is - it is completely HTML5 based and completely client side UI framework. It is one package you need for everything instead of 100s of plugins you would normally do.

Kendo UI is from Telerik - so there is a clear cut release cycles and a world class support backing it.

Here is a live example of how kendo ui can be used to build real world apps

http://www.kendouimusicstore.com/

Music Store is a famous example from Microsoft on ASP.NET MVC. The same example has been re done with Kendo UI powering the UI and WebAPIs in the backend.

Hope this provides you with some insights to your decision making.